# ASP.net MVC 2.0 model binding - creates empty child objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have an asp.net MVC application that was recently upgraded from 1.0 to 2.0.  I use a Linq-to-Sql data model and in a lot of cases, I have been using these as my model objects, as it was simple and seemed to work...

I have a class that has foreign key relationships with two child tables - these child tables will not always be populated (i.e. the foreign key is nullable).

My code (a little simplified) looks something like this:

```
/// This would be the generated linq-to-sql class
public class ModelObject
{
    //Bunch of properties

    public ChildObject { get; set; }

    public ChildObject2 { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
    //Get the current saved object
    ModelObject test = _service.GetModelObject(ID);

    UpdateModel(test);
}
```

Since the upgrade to 2.0, I've found that the updateModel call has been instantiated the two child objects - my save then fails, as some of these have empty fields which are not nullable.  This wasn't happening previous to the upgrade.

Is there a way to stop this from happening (or does anybody have a pointer as to why this has started to happen since the upgrade)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop this from happening by specifying the properties you want to exclude from binding as a parameter in your UpdateModel() call:

```
UpdateModel(test, null, null, new [] { "ChildObject", "ChildObject2"});
```

You can get more information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470388%28v=VS.98%29.aspx).

Comment: I tried something like this (I actually supplied a list of only those properties that I wanted to bind), but this didn't work.